# Changing IP address before web page reads it

Tags: html, security, tcp, proxy, ip

Assume that there is a web-page called whatisyourip.com and that I have a web-page called changeip.com. A user wants to enter the site whatisyourip.com through changeip.com. Normally, changeip.com would be a proxy server so the user can hide his ip address. That's how users reach forbidden web-pages in their countries. But I want to ask, is there a way to show a different ip address to whatisyourip.com while connecting it through changeip.com without using it as a proxy server?

Comment: Depending on the angle this might be a better question for  [serverfault](http://serverfault.com), [superuser](http://superuser.com) or [security](http://security.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: OP, are you trying to hide your IP as well? Or just clients' IPs?

Comment: Just clients' IPs. No need to hide my server's IP.

Answer (score 5):

> is there a way to show a different ip address to whatisyourip.com while connecting it through changeip.com without using it as a proxy server?

Short answer: **Yes**.  Make changeip.com a VPN server and assign different IP addresses to those VPN clients.  Ensure they send all traffic through the VPN.  This usually involves modification of the local routing table on the VPN client workstations for everything to work correctly.

Longer answer... There are several reliable ways to hide IP addresses of TCP sessions...

- [HTTP Proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server#Web_proxy) - you already described this situation
- [Network address Translation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) - this doesn't sound likely in your scenario
- [VPN Tunneling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network) - Possible solution instead of HTTP proxy, even if it's something as simple as an [SSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Sockets_Layer) VPN.  Depending on your constraints, this could also be a viable option.

Comment: Great answer. Just a question though. When I make changeip.com a VPN server, wouldn't it be assigned with just one IP? I want it to be assigned different IPs in different connections.

Comment: @gzg, Most VPN services offer a way to assign unique client IP addresses from a block (also called a pool) of available addresses. If you can use UDP to tunnel your traffic, OpenVPN is an outstanding option that supports address pools for the clients. Regardless of whether you go with a free server (OpenVPN) or something paid (Cisco / Juniper / Checkpoint), you will need technical personnel who understand the details of how VPNs work if you plan to offer this as a service to many people.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. TCP connections require a 3-way handshake. You can certainly send a SYN packet to the server to start the process, then change your IP address. but when the site responds with the 2nd-stage of the handshake (SYN+ACK), that packet is now going to your old IP address and your system will drop it - it has no idea that the server is responding to something that was started on the old IP.

You could try something like the Tor network, which offers end-to-end encryption of traffic and cloaking of origins, but it's not something I'd consider "reliable".

Comment: @MarcB, you are overlooking the possibility of changeip.com being a VPN provider, which assigns different IP addresses.  See my answer for details.

Comment: @Mike: I read the OP's question as "how do I connect through changeip.com without using changeip.com's IP address(es)".

Comment: @MarcB, `is there a way to show a different ip address to whatisyourip.com while connecting it through changeip.com without using it as a proxy server?`  Note what he says **"while connecting it through changeip.com"**.  Speaking as a guy who has been building networks for the last 20 years, you're reading too much into the question when you say "can't use changeip.com's ip addresses"

Comment: if you're connecting through changeip.com, then how can you NOT use their ip addresses? changeip's not going to be "just a router".

Comment: @MarcB, your descriptive assumption of not using their IP address is flawed.  Furthermore, changeip.com can be a "router" (more specifically, a VPN server that routes) and conceal the original IP addresses.  If you don't understand this, go read up on [OpenVPN](http://openvpn.net/)

Comment: "without using it as a proxy server" A VPN is a proxy server, no matter how you look at it.

Comment: @MarcB, we need to disagree on the definition of a VPN server being another form of proxy. In particular, a proxy submits requests on behalf of something else. In many VPNs (but not all), the client Operating System is assigned a different IP address and the client itself makes a new request using the new IP.  That is why I mentioned modifying the routing tables on the client.

Answer (score 0):

Not unless you [spoof your IP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address_spoofing), in which case the response will go to the forged IP. So no.